# React Parent and Child component data flow

Tags: reactjs, parent-child

At loss when it comes to a reusable component I am making in React. The purpose of the component is to get API data and send it to parent where the data in mapped in cards. The component should also be able to receive a function call from the parent that is used to 'load more' data and props which to set whether I search old / new data.

I haven't been able to figure the best way to achieve this or whether I should do it that I through props.children I would display the cards inside the child, hence no need to send data upwards.

Parent:

```
function Page() {

    const [eventData, setEventData] = useState([]);

    const EventCardUpcoming = () => {
        const filterRef = useRef(null);

        const handleClick = () => {
            filterRef.current.callLoad();
        };

        const setData = () => {
            setEventData()
        }

        return (
            <InfiniteScroll
                pageStart={0}
                hasMore={true || false}
                loadMore={handleClick}
            >
                <button onClick={handleClick}>Load more</button>
                <Row className="py-4">
                    <div>
                        <EventFiltering
                            OrganizerId={"1"}
                            ref={filterRef}
                            sendData={setData()}
                        />
                    </div>
                    {eventData ? 
                    <div>
                        {eventData.map((v, i) => (
                            <Col key={i} xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                                <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                    <>
                                        <EventCard eventData={v} />
                                    </>
                                </div>
                            </Col>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                    : null}
                </Row>
            </InfiniteScroll>
        );
    };
    return (
        <Container>
            <EventCardUpcoming />
        </Container>
    );
}

export default Page;
```

Filtering child component:

```
const Filtering = forwardRef((props, ref, { sendData }) => {

    const staticOrganizer = props.OrganizerId; //API configurable option
    
    const paramLimit = 4;
    const [eventData, setEventData] = useState([]);

    let params = {
        org: staticOrganizer,
        limit: paramLimit,
    };

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        callLoad() {
            handleLoadMore(); //load more data from function called in parent
        },
    }));

    useEffect(() => {
        sendData(data); //send data to parent when more is fecthed
    }, [eventData]);

    const handleLoadMore = () => {
        APIGet("getData", params).then((res) => {
            if (res.data.body.length > 0) {
                setEventData((eventData) => eventData.concat(res.data.body));
            }
        });
    };

        return (
            <Container>
                <div>
                    <Dropdowns />
                </div>
            </Container>
        );
    }
);

export default Filtering;
```

Comment: **The purpose of the component is to get API data and send it to parent** - sounds like a hook, not a component to me

Comment: Hi! Bit more complex than that because it as the <Dropdowns /> component through which the user can set several filters to what kind of data to get. I omitted it from code as it functions without and issue and the question is how to receive and send data, props and function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lose the parenthesis

```
sendData={setData}
```

update setMethod to accept data as param

```
  const setData = (data) => {
      setEventData(data)
  }
```